# Meaning {Thing} "decided" to cave in

Tags: meaning

For example:

> "My laptop caved in"

Means that my laptop broke, right?

And when:

> "My laptop decided to cave in"

What does the "*decided*" mean or connote to listeners?
Of course my laptop does not have a human mind to be able to '*decide*'

Could any one explain that?

Comment: Hello, taka-t First, **cave in** is not standard in the sense you give: <<1. Fall in, collapse: The earthquake made the walls cave in. [Early 1700s] //  2. Give in, admit defeat, as in The prosecutor's questions soon made the witness cave in. [Early 1800s] //  3. Collapse, faint, or die from exhaustion, as in After a twenty-mile hike I caved in. [Mid-1800s] >>
[The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cave+in). //// 'My laptop decided to die'  _is_ idiomatic and is a whimsical use of **anthropomorphism** (see eg the ODO definition).

Comment: Yeah, the use of *decided* in that sense is anthropomorphism, where human characteristics are assigned to non-sentient entities.  This is a fairly common thing to do, especially with computers (which often seem to have "a mind of their own").  The use of "cave in" is a sort of metaphor, and similar metaphors are often used to describe computer malfunctions (though, to be specific, "cave in" is one I hadn't seen before, though I can recall cases where it might have been quite appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

People often attribute human-like thought processes, emotions, and autonomy to inanimate things (as Hot Licks observes in a comment above), and for many decades many people have used "decided" as a verb to convey (usually somewhat jocularly) a sense that an inanimate thing has acted of its own volition and for its own inscrutable reasons.

A Google Books search finds examples of such use of *decided* going back at least a century.

From [*The Canadian Alpine Journal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DoUeAQAAMAAJ&q=%22the+weather+decided%22&dq=%22the+weather+decided%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt98DH6KvOAhVl3IMKHTltCBcQ6AEIPjAH), volume 6 (1915) [combined snippets]:

> After this the weather **decided** to be kind for a day or two and the trees round camp were festooned with garments and blankets, while bathing became a luxury instead of a stern and agonizing duty.

From [*Motorcycle Illustrated*](https://books.google.com/books?id=oHoAAAAAMAAJ&q=%22the+moon+decided%22&dq=%22the+moon+decided%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8quX86avOAhXC6YMKHSTMAmkQ6AEIRDAH), volume 15 (1919) [combined snippets]:

> The moon **decided** to work all night without loafing behind a cloud, and everything looked favorable for the polar dash. After rolling through Tacoma's Saturday night traffic, we hit a devilish stretch of muddy road, that could just as well be paved, considering it is one of the highway arteries of Tacoma.

From Richard Ryan, [*Spin It, Dumbwhacks*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BKpJAAAAIAAJ&q=%22my+radio+decided%22&dq=%22my+radio+decided%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRkoCo7KvOAhUn8IMKHSr4AH0Q6AEIIjAB) (1943) [combined snippets]:

> First my throttle stuck in the wide open position. I had no control of the airplane's speed. Tugging and jerking at it, the lever was eventually loosened into working position once more. It was then that my radio **decided** that it had done enough labor for one day. And all of my coaxing and tinkering was to no avail.

From a letter printed in [*The Elevator Constructor*](https://books.google.com/books?id=K1hZAAAAYAAJ&q=%22my+car+decided%22&dq=%22my+car+decided%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh6LLw2KvOAhVk0YMKHRBqCk0Q6AEIKDAC) (1947) [combined snippets]:

> Seems as though a nice slushy ditch was around when my car **decided** to try out the pasture along the highway. Of course that is not the way I explained the situation to my wife (for obvious reasons) so I hope she forgets to read this issue.

In all of these cases the wording is facetious; but there are times when it is easy to believe that some inanimate object—a computer, say—is acting out of a kind of malevolent genius.